# libBox2D.so is missing when compiling SDL2 application for Android on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2017, box2d, sdl-2

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 with Cross Platform Development kit and have managed to compile SDL2 as a dynamic shared library following this steps:
https://trederia.blogspot.hr/2017/03/building-sdl2-for-android-with-visual.html

When deployed on Visual Studio Android Emulator the application runs correctly.

Using the same steps, I also compiled Box2D library. I then added the paths, to the SDL2 application from above and added Box2D in libraries array in SDLActiviy.java and linked the project with libBox2D.so.

But when run on emulator it says this:

https://imgur.com/a/LsI21

I can also see from the compile that Box2D lib is not linked and is not in the libs folder of *.apk file

Anyone knows what I'm missing here?

P.S. I compiled everything with ARM architecture.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error.

Add new project to the original SDL2_Project solution and select Dynamic Shared Library.

Add all the *.cpp files in the Box2D library and compile.

Open SDL2_Application.java and add "Box2D" in the library list.

Right Click on the references in the SDL2_Application and click Box2D checkbox. This will add Box2D library to the final APK packet and will include the compiled lib in the /lib folder of the APK.